# Avoid waiting for user when checking the Apache Tomcat status

Tags: bash, tomcat, systemctl

As part of a bash script I check the recently installed Apache Tomcat status with

```bash
sudo systemctl status tomcat
```

The output is as follows

```bash
● tomcat.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-01-30 16:25:48 UTC; 3min 9s ago
    Process: 175439 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 175447 (java)
      Tasks: 30 (limit: 4546)
     Memory: 253.0M
        CPU: 9.485s
     CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
             └─175447 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.uti>

Jan 30 16:25:48 vps-06354c04 systemd[1]: Starting tomcat.service...
Jan 30 16:25:48 vps-06354c04 startup.sh[175439]: Tomcat started.
Jan 30 16:25:48 vps-06354c04 systemd[1]: Started tomcat.service.
Jan 30 16:25:48 vps-06354c04 systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:1: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
Jan 30 16:25:48 vps-06354c04 systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:2: Assignment outside of section. Ignoring.
```

This is the info I expect to see, but after printing it, `systemctl` keeps waiting for the user to type a key, breaking the automation I expect to deliver.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the **--no-pager** option would keep that from happening.  I just confirmed that on my own system on a different service.  Otherwise, it goes interactive.

Comment: Yes, adding `--no-pager` the paging behaviour is prevented. I also added `--full` as `systemctl` seems to print the 10 first output lines only. Thank you!

Comment: That is correct.  Without "-full", systemctl will only offer a default sampling of 10 items.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall ever seeing `systemctl status` asking for input, so perhaps it's the `sudo` used in this command doing that, in which case you could ask your system administrator to [enable passwordless sudo](https://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux) on the account that runs this command.

A general solution for automating user input in shell scripts is to use [expect](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-expect), but for a simple case where you only need to send a single value one time, you can often get by with using `echo` and piping the value to the command (e.g., `echo 'foo' | sudo systemctl status tomcat`), although you should never do this to pass sensitive information such as passwords because that will potentially be accessible to other users on that system.

Comment: Although Eric's answer is straight to the point I thank you too for the `expect` approach, that may be useful elsewhere in the main script.